# Opening image in python 3.3.2

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I've heard/read alot about the PIL module but i cant get it to work with the current version of Python.

Is there another to just open a simple PNG/JPG/JPEG file and show it ?

With kind regards,

Comment: Show your code...tell us what's not working...

Comment: give a try to [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) then. Also what do you mean with you couln'd get to wkrk PIL? Installation issues? issues when dealing with certain image files?

Comment: Im probabaly installing it wrong. So yes installation issues

Comment: There is NO Python 3 version of PIL. Pillow >= 2.0.0 supports Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4. Here's the [_instructions_](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) for installing Pillow.

Answer (score 0):

PIL has not yet released a Python 3.x update. Instead, consider Pillow.

[Here is the link to Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.5.1) at The Cheese Shop (PyPi), and [a link to some docs for it](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Additionally, you could install it through pip, thusly:

```
pip install pillow
```